# Convert C# animation code to storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I have the following method which works. I'd like to put it in a utility method that returns a Storyboard. Every attempt I have made at converting this to a Storyboard has failed, and I've spent a lot of time researching. I'm ready to give up unless someone comes to my rescue.

Here's the code I want to convert:

```
public override void Begin(FrameworkElement element, int duration)
{
    var transform = new ScaleTransform();
    element.LayoutTransform = transform;

    var animation = new DoubleAnimation
                        {
                            From = 1,
                            To = 0,
                            Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration),
                            FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
                            EasingFunction = new QuinticEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn }
                        };

    transform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, animation);
    transform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, animation);
}
```

So, instead of the two BeginAnimation() calls, I want to return a Storyboard so all I have to do is call storyboard.Begin(). I know this shouldn't be that hard to do, but I'm just not getting it.

Thanks.

EDIT: In response to H.B's suggestions, I tried the following code, which still does not work:

```
private static Storyboard CreateAnimationStoryboard(FrameworkElement element, int duration)
{
    var sb = new Storyboard();
    var scale = new ScaleTransform(1, 1);
    element.RenderTransform = scale;
    element.RegisterName("scale", scale);

    var animation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        From = 1,
        To = 0,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration),
        FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
        EasingFunction = new QuinticEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn }
    };
    sb.Children.Add(animation);

    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, scale);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty));

    return sb;
}
```

I know I only animated the X axis - just want to get something to work first.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two animations and then set the attached `Storyboard` properties to animated the right property on the right object using [`SetTargetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.settargetproperty.aspx) and [`SetTargetName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.settargetname.aspx).

Due to how storyboards work you also need to set a namescope ([`NameScope.SetNameScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.namescope.setnamescope.aspx)), register the name of the transform, and call [`StoryBoard.Begin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.begin.aspx) with the [containing element overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms605709.aspx).

e.g.

```
NameScope.SetNameScope(element, new NameScope());

var transform = new ScaleTransform();
var transformName = "transform";
element.RegisterName(transformName, transform);
element.RenderTransform = transform;

var xAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(2, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var yAnimation = xAnimation.Clone();

var storyboard = new Storyboard()
{
    Children = { xAnimation, yAnimation }
};

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(xAnimation, new PropertyPath("(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(yAnimation, new PropertyPath("(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"));

Storyboard.SetTargetName(xAnimation, transformName);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(yAnimation, transformName);

storyboard.Begin(element);
```

Comment: Yeah, I got that much. Perhaps the details of the complications you mentioned might be helpful?

Comment: @DanThomas: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4567058/546730) sounds like the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but that particular issue is for if you're creating a framework element in code, which I'm not doing. The framework element already exists via xaml, and I'm calling this method via an attached behavior. Any other ideas? :)

Comment: @DanThomas: You are animating the transform, that is what needs a name. Also XAML creation would probably not be enough, you would also need to set a `Name` in XAML, the point is that you *always* need to set the name anyway if you want somethig animated in XAML, otherwise you cannot reference it.

Comment: @DanThomas: Almost, see my edited answer. (I didn't get it to work with `SetTarget`, no idea if that is any use in code)

Comment: I appreciate your help with this, but it's time to give up. I got this error, using your code: InvalidOperationException: No applicable name scope exists to resolve the name 'transform'. I don't want to spend any more time on this for now. But thanks for your help!!

Comment: @DanThomas: That should not happen :( maybe you forgot one the key-points? Well, it's your call, i wouldn't use a storyboard in code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx) and start recording from there, it should create your storyboards in XAML. Rather than hard coding it with C# and trying to translate it 1 by 1 to storyboard thus it can be a prone error.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do them in code. I've created a behavior that I attach to an element and bind to a ViewModel property which allows the ViewModel to trigger an animated visibility transition, with a callback to the ViewModel when it's done. I suppose it's possible to still create the animations in xaml, but since I need the callbacks when they're done, everything is just easier to do in code.